# Change UITabBar style with a switch

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiappearance

I'm trying to make a dark mode switch. I started with this tutorial ([link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/108766/uiappearance-tutorial)), but I can't change the tabBar's style. The navBar's style changes, but the tabBar stays the same.

How can I change the tabBar's appearance without restarting the app?

Update #1: here's the code that I use

```
import UIKit

enum Theme: Int {
    case Light, Dark

    var barStyle: UIBarStyle {
        switch self {
        case .Light:
            return .Default
        case .Dark:
            return .Black
        }
    }

    var backgroundColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .Light:
            return UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.95, blue:0.95, alpha:1.00)
        case .Dark:
            return UIColor(red:0.12, green:0.12, blue:0.12, alpha:1.00)
        }
    }

    var cellBackgroundColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .Light:
            return UIColor(red:1.00, green:1.00, blue:1.00, alpha:1.00)
        case .Dark:
            return UIColor(red:0.15, green:0.15, blue:0.15, alpha:1.00)
        }
    }

    var labelColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .Light:
            return UIColor(red:0.12, green:0.12, blue:0.12, alpha:1.00)
        case .Dark:
            return UIColor(red:0.99, green:0.99, blue:0.99, alpha:1.00)
        }
    }

    var buttonColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .Light:
            return UIColor(red:0.22, green:0.59, blue:0.95, alpha:1.00)
        case .Dark:
            return UIColor(red:0.22, green:0.59, blue:0.95, alpha:1.00)
        }
    }

    var separatorColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .Light:
            return UIColor(red:0.94, green:0.94, blue:0.94, alpha:1.00)
        case .Dark:
            return UIColor(red:0.22, green:0.22, blue:0.22, alpha:1.00)
        }
    }

    var tintColor: UIColor {
        switch self {
        case .Light:
            return UIColor(red:0.62, green:0.62, blue:0.62, alpha:1.00)
        case .Dark:
            return UIColor(red:0.50, green:0.50, blue:0.50, alpha:1.00)
        }
    }
}

class ThemeManager {
    static func currentTheme() -> Theme {
        if(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("darkMode")){
            return .Dark
        } else {
            return .Light
        }
    }

    static func applyTheme(theme: Theme) {
        if(theme == .Dark){
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "darkMode")
        } else {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "darkMode")
        }
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

        let sharedApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        sharedApplication.delegate?.window??.tintColor = theme.buttonColor

        UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = theme.barStyle
        UITabBar.appearance().barStyle = theme.barStyle
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = theme.labelColor

        UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = theme.labelColor

        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = theme.cellBackgroundColor

        UIStepper.appearance().tintColor = theme.tintColor
        UIActivityIndicatorView.appearance().tintColor = theme.tintColor

        UIButton.appearance().tintColor = theme.buttonColor
        UILabel.appearance().textColor = theme.labelColor
    }
}
```

I call `ThemeManager.applyTheme(.Dark || .Light)` when the switch's status changes.

Comment: Can you share some parts of your code, please?

Comment: Updated, let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: The thing is, that your code is fine. You just need to reload your navigation stack. 
In the tutorial that you have used it is also a case. In tutorial code if you will remove `dismiss()` in apply style code part, you will see that it is also doesn't work immediately.

Comment: @PavelGatilov I thought that this might be the issue. How can I reload the navigation stack? The settings view is accessible on a tab and not with a button like in the tutorial, so I can't dismiss it.

Comment: So, the thing that you can potentially do, is actually set tintColor, barStyle etc on current screen directly, without UIAppearance proxy. Then you will have all you need: Current screen will have new style and all feature screens will have style from appearance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIAppearance` proxy only affects new initialised views. Setting colours and styles on `UIAppearance` won't have effect on views that are already visible.

You have to set it manually in ViewController:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barStyle = .Black
```